# Walking through Neo4j starter Node.js code

Tags: node.js, async-await, neo4j, backend

I am fairly new to both node.js and neo4j (and this is my first time building a back-end) so I am confused at some parts of the neo4j starter code for node.js.

1. Why does everything, including the imports, need to be inside an async arrow function? I am not an expert on async/await but it seems weird that imports would need to be inside that.
2. In a context where my back-end is running non-stop, would I never close the driver? But I would close sessions? Is there a simple way to explain the difference between these two entities?

Neo4j starter code for node.js :

```js
(async() => {
    const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

    const uri = "uri";
    const user = "user";
    const password = "password";

    const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
    const session = driver.session()

    const person1Name = 'Alice'
    const person2Name = 'David'

    try {
        // To learn more about the Cypher syntax, see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/
        // The Reference Card is also a good resource for keywords https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/
        const writeQuery = `MERGE (p1:Person { name: $person1Name })
                       MERGE (p2:Person { name: $person2Name })
                       MERGE (p1)-[:KNOWS]->(p2)
                       RETURN p1, p2`

        // Write transactions allow the driver to handle retries and transient errors
        const writeResult = await session.writeTransaction(tx =>
            tx.run(writeQuery, { person1Name, person2Name })
        )
        writeResult.records.forEach(record => {
            const person1Node = record.get('p1')
            const person2Node = record.get('p2')
            console.log(
                `Created friendship between: ${person1Node.properties.name}, ${person2Node.properties.name}`
            )
        })

        const readQuery = `MATCH (p:Person)
                      WHERE p.name = $personName
                      RETURN p.name AS name`
        const readResult = await session.readTransaction(tx =>
            tx.run(readQuery, { personName: person1Name })
        )
        readResult.records.forEach(record => {
            console.log(`Found person: ${record.get('name')}`)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Something went wrong: ', error)
    } finally {
        await session.close()
    }

    // Don't forget to close the driver connection when you're finished with it
    await driver.close()
})();
```

Note that this will throw an error, as I haven't disclosed by username and password for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does everything, including the imports, need to be inside an async
> arrow function? I am not an expert on async/await but it seems weird
> that imports would need to be inside that.

Of course, they don't need to be inside async, as I understood that was the easiest example to present what exactly is required to handle the neo4j connection. Maybe it's worth checking more extensive examples, e.g. [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/nodejs-neo4j-realworld-example)

> In a context where my back-end is running non-stop, would I never
> close the driver? But I would close sessions? Is there a simple way to
> explain the difference between these two entities?

Everything seems to be quite well described inside the neo4j documentation:

- [driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/)
- [session](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/)

Also, it's worth spending some time to understand the concept of drivers, sessions & transactions, as it's common for all databases (relational and non-relational).